# Python - aggregate groupby multiple columns, skipping nan cells

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, nan

I'm trying to aggregate a dataframe accross multiple columns, grouped by `Date`. Some cells contain nan, which I would like to keep. So my df looks like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = ['2015-02-24','2015-02-24','2015-02-24','2015-02-24','2015-02-24','2015-02-24',
       '2015-02-25','2015-02-25','2015-02-25','2015-02-25','2015-02-25','2015-02-25']
rng = pd.to_datetime(rng)
Predicted = [random.randrange(-1, 50, 1) for i in range(12)]
Actual_data = [5,3,8,2,9,20, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]
Category = ['A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B']

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Predicted' : Predicted, 'Actual': Actual_data, 'Category': Category})
```

df

```
          Date  Predicted  Actual Category
0   2015-02-24         0      5.0        A
1   2015-02-24         36     3.0        A
2   2015-02-24         30     8.0        A
3   2015-02-24         33     2.0        B
4   2015-02-24         49     9.0        B
5   2015-02-24         42    20.0        B
6   2015-02-25         25     NaN        A
7   2015-02-25          9     NaN        A
8   2015-02-25         21     NaN        A
9   2015-02-25         39     NaN        B
10  2015-02-25         17     NaN        B
11  2015-02-25         11     NaN        B
```

I Want to group by : `Date` and thereby summing `Predicted` and `Actual`, leaving `Category` out. Also, As I want to maintain the groups that only have NaN, to keep the NaN value, not transforming it to 0. So in the end I would like to have this:

```
          Date  Predicted  Actual 
0   2015-02-24        190      49   
1   2015-02-25        122     NaN
```

I tried things like:

```
df = data.groupby(['Date'])['Predicted', 'Actual'].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

which looked like it worked, but then I saw that it transforms NaN to 0, which I don't want. I tried it with adding `skipna=False`, but it says it's not possible to add it. I did update to the latest version of pandas as I read somewhere that this might be the problem, but it didn't matter. Could someone help me..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could write a lambda function that returns the sum if any of the values are not null, otherwise return NaN

```
df.groupby(['Date'])['Predicted', 'Actual'].agg(lambda x: sum(x) if any(x) else np.nan).reset_index()
```

Output

```
        Date  Predicted  Actual
0 2015-02-24        174    47.0
1 2015-02-25        164     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min_count=1`, this means that minimal 1 valid value is needed to perform the operation:

```
df.groupby(['Date'])[['Predicted', 'Actual']].sum(min_count=1)
```

Output

```
            Predicted  Actual
Date                         
2015-02-24        124    47.0
2015-02-25        162     NaN
```

Why this works and `skipna=False` doesn't, you can read the discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20824).

Comment: I saw this too, but some values might actually be 0 (and I need these included, for example, if all `Predicted` on one day are 0, I want the sum to be 0, not transform it to NaN? Or doesn't it work that way?

Comment: This would still work. `min_count` means: the required number of valid values to perform the operation.

Comment: Ah now I get it, thanks so much, I understood it wrong which is why I didn't try, thank you for this explanation :)